# How to get public folder calendar ID in order to create event using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using Microsoft Graph Explorer I can read all of my calendars.
For that I use GET request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars
```

In these calendars, I cannot see the public folder calendar. Just to mention that I am the Owner of the Public folder calendar and have permission to create a new event.

I use the following POST request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendar ID}/events
```

in order to get all events for some of my calendar IDs and send JSON request using auth token to create a new event in my calendar:

```
{
   'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(session['microsoft_token']),
   'Host': 'graph.microsoft.com',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

Also, I am sending JSON data with specific event data that needs to be created.

But I cannot access to **public folder calendar** until I know **its calendar ID**.

Answer (score 0):

I think that public folders are not supported.

[UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40270642-graph-api-support-for-finding-out-shared-mailboxes)

But only an attempt. Can you try to find your public folder calendar using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders
or
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{folderId}/childFolders
```

If it will find the folder you are looking for then try to use it's id in your request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{public folder calendar ID}/events
```

Comment: With the first request, I can see all my mail folders but I cannot see any public folder.